In Postgresql, how to reset all sequences in a schema so the current value of sequence will match the max values of the primary key
I am refreshing schema data in a Postgresql database. The best and easiest way to do it is dropping the schema and restore it from a backup from the source database. But in this case we are not allowed to drop the schema and the tables. We can only truncate all tables and drop other objects like triggers, functions and sequences. And then run import from the backup, either with psql or pg_restore. Either way, I have to reset the sequences because the import will recreate sequences from the initial starting value, which of course is out of sync with the primary keys that have been created using the sequences when table created.
I tried with the following scripts, it runs but doesn't change anything on any sequence:
DO $$

DECLARE

    seq RECORD;

    tablename TEXT;

    columnname TEXT;

    max_value BIGINT;

BEGIN

    FOR seq IN (SELECT schemaname, sequencename FROM pg_sequences WHERE schemaname = '$TARGET_SCHEMA') LOOP

        
        tablename := (SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema ='$TARGET_SCHEMA') ;

        SELECT kcu.column_name INTO columnname

        FROM information_schema.table_constraints tco

        JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage kcu

        ON kcu.constraint_name = tco.constraint_name

        AND kcu.constraint_schema = tco.constraint_schema

        WHERE tco.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'

        AND tco.table_schema = '$TARGET_SCHEMA'

        AND tco.table_name = tablename

        LIMIT 1;

        IF columnname IS NOT NULL THEN

            EXECUTE 'SELECT COALESCE(MAX(' || quote_ident(columnname) || '), 0) FROM ' || quote_ident('$TARGET_SCHEMA') || '."' || quote_ident(tablename) || '"'

            INTO max_value;

            EXECUTE 'SELECT setval(''' || quote_ident(seq.schemaname) || '."' || quote_ident(seq.sequencename) || '"'', ' || max_value + 1 || ', false)';

        END IF;

    END LOOP;

END

$$;

So please help me debug this scritps. Thank you so much!

To your question add as text update the answers to: 1) Where are you running the DO function? 2) Are you committing after the function is run? 3) What does the Postgres log show is happening? As a comment this We can only truncate all tables and drop other objects like triggers, functions and sequences. makes no sense.

Thank you very much for you response!

I ran this with psql in a shell scripts;
No
Log file has nothing about it.
Regarding the comment, that's my understadning how to refresh a postgresql if I can't drop the whole schema. Please let me know my understanding is incorrect



You don't have to drop the schema you can run pg_restore with -c per pg_restore and it will clean(drop) the objects before restoring them.  2)  Unless you are running in client with autocommit on the changes will not persist past the session. 3) In postgresql.conf make sure log_statement is set to all and reload server to see the statements.  Undo that change once you have seen what you need as it generates a lot of logs

